# Можно ли убрать redirect Яндекс метрики что бы это не повлияло на ее работу?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-метрика

Получается использовал GTmetrix для оптимизации страницы и жалоба пришла на редиректы яндекс метрики смотрите картинку снизу, как можно убрать это редиректы не повлияв на работу метрики?

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter-->
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        if(window.location.hostname != "localhost") {
            (function (d, w, c) {
                (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function () {
                    try {
                        w.yaCounter47676601 = new Ya.Metrika({
                            id: 47676601,
                            clickmap: true,
                            trackLinks: true,
                            accurateTrackBounce: true,
                            webvisor: true,
                            trackHash: true
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                });

                var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
                    s = d.createElement("script"),
                    f = function () {
                        n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
                    };
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.async = true;
                s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

                if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
                    d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
                } else {
                    f();
                }
            })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
        }
    </script>
    <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/47676601" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
    <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter-->
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что происходит внутри Яндекс Метрики внутреннее дело Яндекса. Редиректы там тоже на его стороне. Поэтому скорее всего удалить Вы их сможете только вместе со счётчиком.

P.S. Прогоняя страницы сайта через какой-либо сервис по тестированию, не стоит ему полностью доверять. Там иногда то же ошибаются или что-то не учитывают.